# What do these symbols mean in Lattice Diamond software?

Tags: fpga, lattice

These two pin symbols are in the Lattice Diamond Device View, what is the difference between the two? They both say differential I/O pin when I hover over them.

[image]

Comment: Gacekky1 - Hi, I have reversed (rolled-back) your edit to the question, since afterwards the answer doesn't make sense. It's important not to change a question in a way that makes answers to the original version look invalid or incomplete etc. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you meant the "Device View"? Because the only view I see those is "Package View". Using the "Pin Display Selection Dialog" one can identify the "square wave" icons as PCLK. Information about (primary clock) PCLK and the application of those can be found here: https://www.latticesemi.com/en/Support/AnswerDatabase/2/4/7/2475 .